# Why does IntelliJ IDEA debugger jump to wrong Scala version library?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2 with the Scala plugin version 0.36.431 on Windows 7 with sbt 0.13.1.

The following project definition `build.sbt` has no references to any Scala version other than **2.9.3**.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import AssemblyKeys._
import NativePackagerKeys._

name := "simplews"

version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val sparkVersion = "0.8.1-incubating"

scalaVersion := "2.9.3"

val akkaVersion = "2.0.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.9.3" % sparkVersion  % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-examples_2.9.3" % sparkVersion  % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-tools_2.9.3" % sparkVersion  % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.3" % "1.9.2" % "test"  withSources(),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-repl_2.9.3" % sparkVersion  % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka" % "0.7.2-spark",
  "com.thenewmotion.akka" % "akka-rabbitmq_2.9.2" % "0.0.2" % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % akkaVersion % "compile->default" withSources(),
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % "compile->default" withSources(),
  "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.0.1" % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.9.3" % "1.12.4.1" % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "com.nebhale.jsonpath" % "jsonpath" % "1.2" % "compile->default"  withSources(),
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.8.5",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11"
)

packagerSettings

packageArchetype.java_application

resolvers  ++= Seq(
  "Apache repo" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases",
  "Cloudera repo" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/org/apache/kafka/kafka/0.7.2-spark/",
  "akka rabbitmq" at "http://nexus.thenewmotion.com/content/repositories/releases-public",
  "Local Repo" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + "/.m2/repository",
  Resolver.mavenLocal
)
```

However as seen in the screenshot the debugger has jumped to scala **2.10.2**. Note: the debugger is correctly going to **2.9.3** for some other debugging.

Here is **project/plugins.sbt**:

```
resolvers += "sbt-plugins" at "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.0-RC2")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

**EDIT**   In order to reproduce it is necessary to do a mvn local install on one or two libraries that are not available in any public repo.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file  -Dfile=c:\shared\kafka-0.7.2-spark.jar  -DgroupId=org.apache.kafka -DartifactId=kafka -Dversion=0.7.2-spark  -Dpackaging=jar
```

I had in any case not considered someone (om-nom-nom !) would attempt an exact reproduction - so had also omitted otherwise extraneous items like mergeStrategy and assemblyKeys.

A fully independent reproducible setup may be a bit in coming  - I have been under rather quite heavy demands here.

[image]

Comment: Which version of IDEA are you're using? How your plugins are declared? What is version of scala plugin? (btw, you do mention 2.9.1 and 2.9.2 as well, though it shouldn't be a problem -- just a discrepancy with your statement *build.sbt has no references to any scala version other than 2.9.3*)

Comment: @om-nom-nom  +1 for the precise questioning. OP is updated

Comment: I will try to reproduce your case tomorrow, for now it looks like that newer scala comes from one of your dependencies (likely plugins) and when multiple versions of some library are present IDEA chooses first appearance (which is painful, if you have multiple subprojects with different versions of dependency).

Comment: To see what versions come from what deps look into `target/resolution-cache/reports` where you find the update reports for your project. Not sure why it's not widely proposed as a step to find the root cause in such cases?

Comment: @javadba I tried and failed to reproduce your case with identical configs and similar IDE/plugin versions, sorry  :-( Note also, that your screenshot discloses some of the info that your employee may deem as sensitive.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski because not everybody knows about it :-) as well as about [this cozy plugin for sbt](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski +1 I will look into the target/resolution-cache/reports

Comment: @om-nom-nom   I think you had a note there that you had attempted to reproduce - and one or more libraries were missing.  I had to do mvn local install on a couple of items due to non-availability in the repos.